# PyQt5 import Error

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to create a GUI that I can all it from the terminal (Ubuntu here). The problem is, whenever I try to run the code *from* the terminal, I get the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "alert.pyw", line 3, in <module>
    from   PyQt5.QtCore    import *
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5'
```

The problem is: I only get this message when I try to call the program from the terminal using

```
python3 alert.pyw Hello
```

PyQt5 is installed and when I import it from the shell it (apparently) works fine...

Comment: install pyqt5 with sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5

Comment: I already did it, but still not working...